# margin only affects width and not top

Tags: html, css

So I want to put a div in a div and set a margin for the inner one. So it should look like this

[image]

but currently the margin only affects the width, not the height.

```css
#outer {
  background: red;
}

#inner {
  background: blue;
  margin: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    foo
  </div>
</div>
```

The margin adds vertical space but the outer div moves down instead of stretching. Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing  Maybe this will answer your questions.

Comment: margin flows outside or border, that's why its happening, use padding on outer div instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Margins collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)

> If there is no border, padding, inline content, height, or min-height to separate a block's margin-top from its margin-bottom, then its top and bottom margins collapse.

So we can fix this by adding an invisible border to the outer element

```css
#outer {
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

#inner {
  background: blue;
  margin: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    foo
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use inner padding instead:

```css
#outer {
  background: red;
  padding: 40px;
}

#inner {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    foo
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This might be a solution, but does not answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this using flexbox :

```css
#outer {
  background: red;
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

#inner {
  background: blue;
  margin: 40px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    foo
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this approach, where you set the display of the inner div to inline block, then give it a height and a width

```css
#outer {
  background: red;
}

#inner {
  background: blue;
  margin: 20%;
  display:inline-block;
  width:60%;
  height:60vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    foo
  </div>
</div>
```